# How pass a initialized bean in a session scope to another session scope?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, session-scope

I have a login page, which I check if the user exist in my database, if so, the bean `user`  is initialized then I redirect to `myprofile.xhtml` page, but there (in `myprofile.xhtml`) I would like to catch the user values with another `ManageBean`.
Just to don't mess with the resposabilities of each view and `ManageBean.`

**UPDATE**
Follow BalusC approach:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Profile implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5621841046523030920L;

    @ManagedProperty("#{login.mUser}")
    private User user;


    // getter and setter
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }


    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

I would like to catch only the initialized object mUser (model).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject beans in each other by [`@ManagedProperty`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedProperty.html).

E.g.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserManager userManager;

    private User user;

    // ...
}
```

and

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Profile {

    @ManagedProperty("#{userManager}")
    private UserManager userManager;

    // ...
}
```